# How to adjust the parentheses size in acro package?

Tags: acronyms, acro, parentheses, chemformula

I'm using the `acro` package for my acronyms. Some of these acronyms are mathematics and chemical formulas. The `acro` package put the acronym in the text using first the long form and then, between parantheses, the short form. How can I modify the parentheses size automatically for to adjust to the short form when is a formula?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{acro}
%
\DeclareAcronym{DNA}{
short=DNA,
long=deoxyribonucleic acid
}
\DeclareAcronym{OH}{
short=\ensuremath{\left[\chlewis{90:180:270:}{O}\ch{-H}\right]^{-}},
long=hydroxy group
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms\par
%
How it looks: \acf{DNA} and \acf{OH}\par
%
How I want:
deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) and
hydroxy group $\left(\left[\chlewis{90:180:270:}{O}\ch{-H}\right]^{-}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Christian the parentheses around the short form are placed by `acro`.

Comment: If you use so large formula in normal text in a paragraph they will push the lines apart.

Answer (score 1):

By defining a custom first style you can customise the braces used.  `\DeclareFirstStyle{AZbraces}{inline}{brackets-type=AZ}` would use `A` and `Z` instead of `(` and `)` to enclose the short form.

The `brackets-type` key expects just two tokens, so we need to define the macros which both start math-mode and place a larger bracket, e.g.

```
\newcommand\mBigop{\(\Big(}
\newcommand\mBigcl{\Big)\)}

\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{Bigbrace}{inline}{
brackets-type=\mBigop\mBigcl
}
```

This can be used to both get fixed-size brackets with `\Big(` and co or variable-size with `\left(`/`\right)`, the appropriate bracket style can then be applied to specific acronyms using the `first-style` key in `\DeclareAcronym`.

In a full example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{acro}

\newcommand\mBigop{\(\Big(}
\newcommand\mBigcl{\Big)\)}
\newcommand\mleftop{\(\left(}
\newcommand\mrightcl{\right)\)}

\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{Bigbrack}{inline}{
brackets-type=\mBigop\Bigcl
}
\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{lrbrack}{inline}{
brackets-type=\mleftop\mrightcl
}

\DeclareAcronym{DNA}{
short=DNA,
long=deoxyribonucleic acid
}
\DeclareAcronym{OH}{
short=\ensuremath{\left[\chlewis{90:180:270:}{O}\ch{-H}\right]^{-}},
long=hydroxy group,
first-style=Bigbrack,
}

\DeclareAcronym{OH2}{
short=\ensuremath{\left[\chlewis{90:180:270:}{O}\ch{-H}\right]^{-}},
long=hydroxy group,
first-style=lrbrack,
}

\begin{document}
\printacronyms

How it looks: \acf{DNA} and \acf{OH}

How it looks: \acf{DNA} and \acf{OH2}

\makebox[0pt][l]{How I want:}\phantom{How it looks:}
deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) and
hydroxy group $\left(\left[\chlewis{90:180:270:}{O}\ch{-H}\right]^{-}\right)$
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Compiled code]

I would prefer the use of `\Big(`/`\Big)` for your example as `\left(\right)` produce larger than necessary brackets which, given they are appearing inline with text, is undesirable as it creates excessive gaps between the lines.

One obvious caveat is if the short form is not intended to be typeset in math mode it will need to be entered as `short=\ensuremath{\text{Foo}}`.  Though using any large brackets should be the exception.